# Computing singular homology of circle using only the definition

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute the first singular homology $H_1(S^1, \mathbb{Z})$ without referring to any classical theorems which are usually used for it.

What I have already done. Let $u : [0,1] \to S^1 $ be an element of $  C_1(S^1, \mathbb{Z})$ then we introduce $U: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ to be it's lifting to the universal cover $\mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{p} S^1$, i.e. $u = p \circ U$. It allows us to define $\operatorname{ind} u : = U(1) - U(0)$ which doesn't depend on the choice of lifting. For an arbitrary element $x = \sum k_iu_i \in C_1(S^1, \mathbb{Z}) $ we set $\operatorname{ind}x : = \sum k_i \operatorname{ind}u_i$.

It's quite easy to show that if $x \in C_1(S^1, \mathbb{Z})$ represents a homology class, i.e. $\partial x = 0 $ then $ \operatorname{ind}x \in \mathbb{Z}$. It's also straightforward that if $x $ is a boundary then $\operatorname{ind}x = 0$.

Now I am struggling to show that if $\operatorname{ind}x = 0$ then it's a boundary. If I do that then it's just additivity remains.

Comment: If $U(0) = U(1)$, then you can view it as a map $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$.  Since $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, it extends to a map $D^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @J126, sorry I don't understand your idea

Comment: What does it mean for an element of $C_1(S^1, \mathbb{Z})$ to be a boundary?  For me, it means that there is a map in $C_2(S^1, \mathbb{Z})$ that it is the boundary of.

Comment: This just seems like the Hurewicz isomorphism for n = 1 with extra steps.

Comment: @J126 yes, but I don't understand the rest.

Comment: @Noel Lundström kind of, but the exercise sheet says we are not ready to prove the general case yet. I saw the proof of Hurewicz theorem  in Hatchers's  book and I don't understand several steps there.

Comment: So you want to prove that the function $\text{ind} : C_1(S^1,\mathbb Z) \to \mathbb R$ induces an isomorphism $H_1(S^1) \to \mathbb Z$. You should perhaps explicitly mention this in your question.